# Configure site onto the server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, putty, filezilla

I am working on Zend Framework and I configured it into my Ubuntu 11.04. I created the virtual host for it and it running successfully into my localhost.

Now recently I have got task from my client to configure the same code onto the server. So my question is how to configure it onto server, is it require virtual host for it or not and whats the process of it. I have File Zilla and Putty SSH client on my machine.

So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to clarify that question a lot more - far too much missing details to help.

Comment: @Robbie: What details actually you want. I'll provide you that

Comment: What is the problem you want solving? Right now we need to guess what needs configuring - do you have a server set up, what OS is it, does it have a FQDN, does it have PHP, does it have apache, does it have MySQL, is it running other sites, are you strugglign with configuring your actual applicaiton (i.e. setting to connect to the DB)... What precisely do you want help with?

Answer (score 1):

To put your Zend Application in production, you just have to put it on a root domain for exemple in root directory of example.org or mysite.example.org but not in a directory wich url will be example.org/testApp/myApp.
See the Zend Framework Documentation too.